# What is the name of the video signal recognized by this monitor?

Tags: video

[image: copy of old manual]

I have a hobby project with an old CP/M-80 system where the monochrome monitor is showing its age as the image is flickering a lot.  I was wondering if I could attach a modern monitor or tv-screen, but I am not sure what standard the signal is called today.

I found this page describing the monitor characteristics (as far as I can tell from https://datamuseum.dk/bits/30001066 an adapted version of a NEC JB-1201M(A)), which says

- 50 Hz frame frequency.
- 275 active scan lines
- 33 vertical blanking intervals
- 308 total scan lines
- 15.4 kHz line frequency ~= 65 microsecond line period time

Is this just simply 240p (which my game capture device will be able to understand when I get a BNC-RCA adapter cable) or is it called something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not 240p because that's generally a term for 60 Hz non-interlaced signal. You have 275 active lines which is more that the 240 active lines, and even more than the total 262 lines for a 240p signal.

A 50Hz non-interlaced signal has typically 312 total lines at 15.625 kHz so this signal with 15.4 kHz and 308 lines should be approximately compatible with any TV system capable of displaying a 50 Hz 625-line monochrome signal. This includes monochrome TVs, PAL TVs and SECAM TVs.

So best name for this 50 Hz signal could be 288p as it is compatible with 576i.

Comment: Ah, PAL makes sense as this is an European system.  576i sounds like most tv's around here will be capable,.   Thanks.

Comment: @MartinMaly I deliberately did not mention PAL because it is only a color encoding method that can be used with any TV system, and the device outputs a monochrome signal and any TV which can show a 50 Hz 625-line signal can show it, including monochrome TVs, PAL TVs and SECAM TVs.

Comment: @Justme Nevertheless, PAL is commonly understood as referring to a 625-line 50Hz frame format, particularly in contrast to NTSC.